# Evaluating variables from a list of names in bash

Tags: bash

```
vars="a,b"
a="True"
b="False"
IFS=","
for var in $vars; do
  if [[ "$var" = "True" ]]; then
    echo "True found"    
  fi
done
```

I would expect the above bash script to print out "True found". But it does not print anything. Any ideas as to why ?

Comment: `vars="a,b"` is not an array

Comment: @Blender `$vars` is not an array expansion so I don't think that was the expectation.

Comment: You want indirect variables. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006

Comment: You are expecting bash to double-evaluate the variable contents. It isn't going to do that. You need to do the second level of indirection yourself.

Comment: ...as it is, err, why would you expect `$var` to evaluate to `True` or `False`, rather than `a` or `b`?

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of this script to see what is actually happening at each step to better understand what is going on.

Comment: As an aside, you should also consider using native bash arrays when you want a list of strings. `vars=( a b ); for var in "${vars[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: ...but then, in most cases you might think of using indirect variables, you can (and often should) use associative arrays instead. `declare -A vars=( [a]=True [b]=False ); for key in "${!vars[@]}"; do value=${vars[$key]}; printf 'Key %q has value %q\n' "$key" "$value"; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this:

```
if [[ "${!var}" = "True" ]]; then
```

`${!varname}` expands the variable named in `$varname`. Otherwise, you get the name itself, not the contents of the variable with that name.

See [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for far more details.

Comment: Indirect variables. Nice. TIL.